# web2py update_or_insert to increment a counter

Tags: sql-update, counter, sql-insert, web2py

I have a web2py-defined database table which is used to count the number of times a request has been made by a particular user - so it has integer columns 'user_id' and 'n_req'. I don't want to populate this with a zero for each possible user. Instead, I want to check if a row with the user_id exists and if so, increment the 'n_req' by one, otherwise create it with an initial value of 'n_req' of 1. To avoid race conditions, I'd like to do this using a single update_or_insert call, e.g.

```
db.count_table.update(db.count_table.user_id == uid, user_id = uid, n_req = n_req + 1)
```

I presume I can't do this, however, as it is using the pre-existing value of `n_req` when incrementing. So how do I tell the DAL the initial value for `n_req`. Can I do, for example, `n_req = (n_req || 0) + 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to use the `.update_or_insert` method in this case because the value of `n_rec` is conditional on whether a record is found. Instead, you can do something like this:

```
db.define_table('count_table',
    Field('user_id', 'integer', unique=True),
    Field('n_rec', 'integer', default=1))

def update_count(user_id):
    return db(db.count_table.user_id == user_id).update(n_rec=db.count_table.n_rec + 1)

if not update_count(uid):
    try:
        db.count_table.insert(user_id=uid)
    except db._adapter.driver.IntegrityError:
        update_count(uid)
```

Note that the value of `n_rec` in `.update` is set to `db.count_table.n_rec + 1`, which will translate to a SQL statement that will let the database increment the existing value rather than explicitly providing the final value yourself. This should avoid race conditions in case two requests are updating the count at the same time.

Also, note there is a `unique` constraint on the `user_id` field. This will prevent a race condition from allowing two records to be created for the same user. In that case, the `try/except` will catch the resulting `IntegrityError`, and an update will be made on the existing record.

Comment: Thanks @anthony. What happens if between the first 'db.count_table' call and the 'insert' another process adds the row in. I guess this will fail, so was hoping for a way to do it atomically.

Comment: Good point. The above code will avoid race conditions on updates, but you could still get a race condition with the initial insert. To avoid that problem, you should place a `unique` constraint on the `user_id` field to prevent the app from creating two records for the same user. You can then wrap the `insert` in a `try/except` to catch violations of the unique constraint. Upon such an exception, check again for an existing record, and do an update instead of an insert.

Comment: I updated the answer to handle race conditions on insert as well.

Comment: Thanks @Anthony. It's a shame this is all so complex! I was sort-of hoping for an easy one-liner solution. But I guess that's race conditions for you.